# Why dont the implied probabilities of odds sum to 1?

Tags: probability

If an outcome $B$ has odds $x$ then for any $1$ dollar bet on $B$ you will get $x$ dollars if $B$ happens and you will lose your stake if it doesnt.

Now I ran into a problem.

Take a two outcome game with outcomes $A$ and $A'$.
The odds for $A$ is $1.7$, the odds for $A'$ is $2.2$.
The margin earnt by the book maker can be  calculated by: $M=(1/1.7 +1/2.2 )-1=0.043...$ the implied probabilities can then be calculated $p_A=(1-M)/1.7$ and $p_{A'}=(1-M)/2.2$.

However in my case I got $0.563...$ and $0.435...$ which sums to $0.9981...$. What is the mistake I made?

Comment: Which way you got odds for $A$ and $A'$? There is no rule that for any two odds appropriate probabilities sum to 1. Imagine you have for example $1.1$ for $A$ and $1.2$ for $A'$. Than you can hardly expect that appropriate probabilities sum to 1.

Comment: You would be right, except thats why the first thing i do is calculate the implied margin. If we have only 2 possible outcomes, then 2 odds will uniquely define a margin. Then once we have a margin, we can always find the unique probabilities by normalizing on 1-margin.

Answer (score 3):

The problem is that $$\begin{align}(1-M)/1.7+(1-M)/2.2)&=1/1.7+1/2.2-M/1.7-M/2.2\\&=(1+M)-M/1.7-M/2.2\\&=1+M\cdot(1-1/1.7-1/2.2)\\&=1-M^2\end{align}$$ instead of $1$ (unless the bookie is fair, i.e., $M=0$). More promising expressions for probabilities seem to be $$p_A=\frac1{1.7\cdot (1+M)}, \qquad p_{A'}=\frac1{2.2\cdot (1+M)}$$